# How to run this moment.js code from node.js to angular.js controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, momentjs, angular-moment

I have this node.js code below;

```
var moment = require('moment')
var myDate = new Date("2008-01-01");
myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + 13);
var answer = moment(myDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

I would like to run it in angularjs. I followed the instructions in https://github.com/urish/angular-moment and have added the necessary links and modules.

I would like to run the code in my angularjs controller.

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
    .controller('OwnCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', '$window', 'configuration', 
                            function($scope, $http, $timeout, $window, $configuration) 
{
}
```

Problem is I cannot call `var moment = require('moment')` in angularjs, unlike in node.js. How can this be done inside an angularjs controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use Node.js module on Angular code, but you can install angular-moment, inject files and dependencies as stated in the README and the use it like this:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).controller('OwnCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', '$window', 'configuration', 'moment',
function ($scope, $http, $timeout, $window, $configuration, moment) {
    var myDate = new Date("2008-01-01");
    myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + 13);
    var answer = moment(myDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
}]);
```

Comment: You also need to register the dependency to angularMoment when defining the module

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your code as follows:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', ['angularMoment'])
    .controller('OwnCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', '$window', 'configuration', 'moment', 
                            function($scope, $http, $timeout, $window, $configuration, moment) 
{
    //use as in node
    var newDate = moment();
}
```

In this case you use the normal angular-js dependency injection